# What does "intermixing" mean here?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am reading *Empire’s Crossroads: A History of the Caribbean from Columbus to the Present Day* by Carrie Gibson.

I have difficulty understanding the word *intermixing*.

> "But after Columbus, the incarnation of the Carib took a variety of turns: Kalinago described the people of Dominica and Grenada, and the people of St Lucia and St Vincent were later called ‘black Caribs’ because there was **intermixing** between runaway slaves and indigenous people – and they were known for their fierce resistance. "

Does it mean marriage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermixing means exactly what it means here.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intermix):

> intermix
>   verb (used with or without object)
>   1.
>   to mix together; intermingle.

Since this sentence just provides a reason for the other one, we can take it out of context and look at it that way:

> There was intermixing between runaway slaves and indigenous people.

If we were to remove unnecessary words that could just be "them" or "it" or "these stuff":

> There was intermixing between A and B.

And there you have it, this would mean A and B were now mixed together, practically impossible to tell apart or separate.

In the context of your example, runaway slaves are now among the indigenous people and they're all mixed in together. Marriage may occur later on, and it probably does since a lot of people got mixed in together, but that word does not mean that it happened.

Answer (score 2):

It means sexual relations between runaway slaves and indigenous people that result in the offsprings being labeled as Black Caribs. Marriage may or may not occur.